# Regex construction assistance

Tags: regex

I've become stuck constructing a regex, and was wondering if you guys could help me out.

Here's the full string:

```
/20271/Avtal%202013/Sammanst%c3%a4lld_produktlista_2013_v121220_l%c3%a5st_web.xls
```

I want to extract **2013_v121220** but the matching must follow a couple of rules:

- Total length of version string must at least be 4 characters
- It must allow for version strings that do not contain either "v" or "_", i.e. **2013121220** or **2013_121220**
- The version string must be the last occurrence before the end of the string (i.e. do not match /**20271**/ in this case).

I've tried with `(\d+[_v]*\d+).*?_web(\.xlsx?)$` but I have no idea how to implement the length check here, i.e. `(\d+[_v]*\d+)` has to be at least 4 characters, `{4,}`, this to not match the **5** in `_l%c3%a5st_web.xls`.

---

I've come up with this regex: `(\d[\d_v]{2,}\d).*?_web(\.xlsx?)$` but it only matches the first occurence, I need the last one, closest to the end. I've tried prefixing `.+` to the regex but it fails regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself. Thanks for your efforts though, I really appreciated your 
help.

This regex matches exactly according to my rules:

```
(\d[\d_v]{2,}\d)(?!.*\d[\d_v]{2,}\d).*?_web(\.xlsx?)$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=produktlista_)(\d{1,}(?:_v)\d{1,}|\d{4,})
```

this will get you the value of productlista

editing anubhavas regex

```
\d{1,}(?:_v)?\d{1,}(?=.*?_web\.xlsx?$)
```

demo here  : http://regex101.com/r/pW6mV8

Comment: As my previous comment, your regex won't match for example **5_v5**.

Comment: Minimum 4 characters, could be digits or together with `_` or `v`.

Comment: Yeah I've tried it and it didn't work. See my rules. It matches *produktlista_21_l%c3%a5st_web.xls* (21) which is wrong, must be at least 4 chars. Plus it matches all occurrences, not just the last

Comment: check here and tell if its failing any of your scenarios : http://regex101.com/r/lQ3aR8

Comment: Nice solution there, but it still must match **2013_121220** for example. The **v** is optional as well. Great site by the way, first time I learn about it.

Comment: @silkfire i think this should be it : (?<=produktlista_)(\d{1,}[_v]+\d{1,}|\d{4,})

Comment: The regex shouldn't be dependent on *produktlista*, plus it doesn't match in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(?=\d*\d.{2}\d\d*\D)\d+(?:_v)?\d+(?!.*?\d(?:_v)?\d)(?=.*?_web\.xlsx?$)
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eD6bE3)

Comment: Yeah, but that won't match **produktlista_5_v5_l%c3%a5st_web.xls**. `5_v5` is 4 characters too.

Comment: `_v` should be optional

Comment: @silkfire: Where is version number in `produktlista_5_v5_l%c3%a5st_web.xls`?

Comment: 5_v5, the version number always starts and ends with a digit.

Comment: And is there always `_v` in between?

Comment: No, `_` and `v` is optional.

Comment: So `1234` appears anywhere in string is also a version?

Comment: @anubhava Correct, but it must be the last occurrence before **xls** (the end of string), so it can't e.g. match **20271** at the beginning of the string.